# Не запускается скрипт через cron

Tags: cron

В cron'e строка вида:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/wget http://site.ru/main/cron/updateSystemLoad?token=TOKEN > /tmp/zxcron.log 2>&1
```

В `zxcron.log` выводит следующее:

```
--2016-10-15 19:45:01--  http://site.ru/main/cron/updateSystemLoad?token=TOKEN
Resolving site.ru (site.ru)... 195.2.72.155
Connecting to site.ru (site.ru)|195.2.72.155|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received.
Retrying.

--2016-10-15 19:45:02--  (try: 2)  http://site.ru/main/cron/updateSystemLoad?token=TOKEN
Connecting to site.ru (site.ru)|195.2.72.155|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received.
Retrying.
```

Через браузер скрипт работает прекрасно. Дело именно в запуске через крон. Строка из крона тоже взята с другого сервера (debian), там работает.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем дело?

Comment: А вы к своему сайту подключаетесь? Может быть нужно передать идентификатор через параметр wget'а `--user-agent=`? Обращались в тех. поддержку сайта? Если запустить wget руками из консоли - что будет?

Comment: @МАН69К, да, к своему. К сожалению, тех.поддержка этим не занимается. Руками через консоль - тоже самое.

По поводу идентификатора - можете привести пример? Просто не понял.

Comment: "тоже самое" - имеется в виду тоже, что и через cron, или тоже, что и через браузер? Попробуйте записать примерно так: `wget --user-agent="Opera/9.80 (X11; Linux x86_64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.16" http://site.ru....`

Comment: @МАН69К, имелось ввиду - тоже самое что и через крон.
Добавил такую строку: wget --user-agent="Opera/9.80 (X11; Linux x86_64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.16" http://site.ru/main/cron/updateSystemLoad?token=TOKEN > /tmp/zxcron.log 2>&1
в итоге при выходе из редактора, ошибка: crontab: installing new crontab
"/tmp/crontab.8jENaF/crontab":22: bad minute
errors in crontab file, can't install.
Do you want to retry the same edit? (y/n)

Comment: 1. про какой именно скрипт речь? 2. из каких соображений вы пришли к выводу, что скрипт не запускается? 3. приведите вывод команды `/usr/bin/wget http://site.ru/main/cron/updateSystemLoad?token=TOKEN`

Comment: @alexander barakin, скрипт как скрипт, не думаю, что стоит описывать его функционал. К чему это? Если скрипт работает через браузер и успешно запускается на другом сервере debian. В логах ошибка - из этих соображений пришел к тому, что скрипт не выполняется.

Answer (score 1):

cron у вас занимается судя по вашему логу,далее прорамма wget делает запрос по указанному url адресу, но сервер не отдает данные по неизвестной причине (как вам сказали, возможно следует передать user agent). Ошибку сохранения вы получаете по причине неверного формата времени запуска - обратите внимание на звездочки и цифры вначале строки.

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте то что вас попросил сделать МАН69К, а именно wget --user-agent="Opera/9.80 (X11; Linux x86_64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.16" http://site.ru....

Если начнет работать, можно приступать ко правке cron так как по вашему комментарию видно что вы допустили в нем ошибку в 22 строке **("/tmp/crontab.8jENaF/crontab":22: bad minute errors in crontab file, can't install. Do you want to retry the same edit? (y/n)**)

Comment: Понимаете, я когда добавляю эту строку которую мне скинул МАН69К, у меня выходит ошибка. Как я могу дальше продолжить, если у меня ошибка?

Comment: Если вам нужно решить проблему то выполните следующую команду ( В КОМАНДНОЙ СТРОКЕ) наберите  

**wget http://site.ru/main/cron/updateSystemLoad?token=TOKEN**

ВАЖЕН ВЫВОД КОМАНДЫ (как уже сказано ранее в комментариях)

Если не будет работать, тогда нужно будет запустить ТАКУЮ КОМАНДУ

 **wget --user-agent="Opera/9.80 (X11; Linux x86_64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.16" http://site.ru/main/cron/updateSystemLoad?token=TOKEN**


Все команды запускаются из командной строки не из CRON

Comment: вывод точно такой же как и в 1-ом посте. Что просто через wget ......, что через wget --user-agent ..........

Comment: Тогда ошибку нужно искать на стороне сервера. Скрипт **updateSystemLoad**. Запускается ли он вообще когда вы его вызываете через wget? Распечатать переменные сервера, командную строку ...

Comment: понимаете, скрипт работает через браузер, мало того - он работает на другом сервере дебиан. Может ли дело быть в апаче? Просто у меня путь к файлу идет через поддомен. Хотя, на другом сервере (где работает) всё было так же...

Comment: Так это и надо выяснить - посмотреть логи Apache, что он выдает в ответ на ваш запрос, а также выяснить, запускается ли ваш скрипт вообще...

Comment: логи апача смотрю каждую секунду. Ничего связанного с cron, wget и т.д - нет. Сейчас пробую через curl - вообще ничего не выводит о том, успешно или не успешно, ошибок нет, но не работает.

Comment: В логах ничего и не будет про cron и wget. В логах пишется IP адрес с которого был запрос, запрашиваемый ресурс, код ответа сервера. Вы же знаете ваш IP, можете привести фрагмент log файла связанный с вашим запросом...

Comment: если бы проблема была связана с wget, разве в логах апача не было бы ошибки? И для запроса у меня так и так свой лог, посмотрите 1-ый пост.

Comment: Судя по вашему первому посту, соединение происходит успешно, только вот ответа пустой. Есть ли вообще в логах упоминание про ваш запрос? Если есть то что пишет Apache ?

Comment: В логах Apache ничего с кроном связанного нет вообще.

Comment: @Максим: как вы проверяете связь логов с кроном? Надеюсь не ищете слово "cron"? Сравнивайте по времени запроса (если время на сервере и компьютере, где выполняете wget) совпадает. А так же добавьте логирование в тот скрипт, который выполняется при запросе `updateSystemLoad`.

Comment: На машине с кроном `ping site.ru` отрабатывает нормально? Нет проблем с DNS?  В настройках web-сервера или в настройках этого сайта (именно в коде или `.htaccess`)  нет-ли ограничений на user-agent и/или ip-сети?